# I want to store latitude and longitude in realtime FIrebase....And have the following code

Tags: android, firebase, location

This is my code to view latitude and longitude of current location in android. I want to save the location in firebase. I have removed the code to view the location thus to store location in database. I want to save the current location to firebase then retrieve it later.

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient client;
    private LatLng lng;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

requestPermission();
        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        EditText EditText  = findViewById(R.id.ed);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MapsActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    // TODO: Consider calling
                    //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                    // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                    //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                    //                                          int[] grantResults)
                    // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                    // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                    return;
                }
                client.getLastLocation().addOnSuccessListener(MapsActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        if(location!=null)
                        {


                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
public void requestPermission()
{

ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);

}

}
```

Comment: Please add the code that you are using to add the data, get the data and your database structure.

Answer (score 0):

First, register with firebase Console and get the JSON data after that you can point the Database Reference and their corresponding child.

```
if(location!=null)
{
    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase.child("Location").child("Lat").setValue(location.latitude);
}
```